# How can I delete database records from a jsp page?

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jdbc

The following code is a part of my project and the output of this code is that I get all the title of the posts in the database and a delete hyperlink in front of all enteries. When I click delete for a respective title it should be deleted from jsp page. How to write code for this?

```
<label><h3>Post published:</h3></label>
      <%
               rs = stmt.executeQuery("select title from Postdata");
       %>

                <table id="rounded-corner" summary="all posts">

                    <tbody>
                        <% while (rs.next()) {%>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%=rs.getString(1)%>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <a href><%=""%>Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <%}%>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

[image: Screen shot of this code]

Comment: Do they still code JSP like that?

Comment: Should it be deleted only from page? Or from database also?

Comment: It would be better if it is deleted from database also..

Comment: @ring Nope. Highly discouraged.

Comment: @ring, @ andrew : Respected members, i'm just a beginner in advanced java (jsp, servlet etc) so that is why i am writing the way i know. Plz help to solve the query.

Comment: You should be using a servlet to perform all of the database operations, etc and not having them be performed within the jsp page.

Comment: If everyone wants me to write database operations in servlet, still what code i have to write??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal way to do this is to move all logic to a Servlet. This method I mention below is not recommended for many reasons you will learn as you gain more experience. However for now let us assume you are going to use only JSPs. There are many ways to do this, but this is one of the ways.

This method uses two JSPS, first JSP to display the records. The second JSP is a processing JSP which will do the deleting for you.

More in the detail below.

The first JSP will display the records.
The second JSP is invoked when you click on "delete".

The second JSP would delete the record and then redirect back to the first JSP. This is a very inefficient way to do this and is not recommended. But it is quick and dirty and will save you time from creating Servlets, Java files etc.

**JSP1.jsp** 
 will have the same code as you posted. retrieve the primary key of the record as well. This will be used to identify the record that needs to be deleted.
This id will be passed as a parameter to the second JSP.

```
<%
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("select primary_key_id, title from Postdata");
%>
  <table id="rounded-corner" summary="all posts">

     <tbody>
        <% while (rs.next()) {
             String primaryKey = rs.getString(1);
        %>
         <tr>
             <td>
                <%=rs.getString(2)%>
             </td>
             <td>

                 <a href ="JSP2.jsp?deleteid=<%=primaryKey%>">Delete</a>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <%}%>

        </tbody>
     </table>
```

**JSP2.jsp**
retrieve the parameter from the request. Then execute the Delete query for that id.
Then redirect back to JSP1.

```
<%
    String recordToDelete = request.getParameter("deleteid");

    // Use PreparedStatements here instead of Statment
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("delete from Postdata where primary_key_id="+ recordToDelete );

     response.sendRedirect("JSP1.jsp"); // redirect to JSP one, which will again reload.
%>
```

This method is not recommended, but you get an idea what needs to be done.

Comment: When a searchbot comes along to crawl the links... Bye bye records!

Comment: @BalusC I totally agree. Thats why I have disclaimers in the beginning and end of the post. However I am assuming he needs this for learning purposes and wont be putting it out live.

Comment: @kensen john : i'm getting this error when i executed the above code. javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'primary_key_id'.

Comment: @user936516 I used primary_key_id as an example, you have to use the column name holding the row id, specific to the table you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you really want to use JSTL instead of 'raw' java in JSP files.
And, like the previous commenter already mentioned, you would put this 
logic nowadays in a servlet/controller.

If you really like to do this with an jsp, the code should look something like this (using jstl):

```
<sql:setDataSource var="ds" ... />
<c:set var="title" value="${param['title']}"/>

<sql:update dataSource="${ds}">
   DELETE FROM Postdata where title = ?
   <sql:param value="${title}" />
</sql:update>
```

Where you create the link as following:

```
<td><a href="?title=[title to remove]">Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: When a searchbot comes along to crawl the links... Bye bye records!

Comment: You're absolute right about that ;-) Just followed the orginal code. Good call.

Comment: @ lauwie : Thank You for the help. I will learn my basics of servlets properly.

Answer (score 4):

Create a POST form with the record ID as hidden input value and a submit button. I assume that your table has an `id` column and that you've selected it as well.

```
<form action="delete" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=rs.getLong("id")%>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

In the servlet (or JSP if you really need it to be), just grab the ID as request parameter

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
```

Then just do your JDBC thing.

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM PostData WHERE id = ?");
preparedStatement.setLong(1, Long.valueOf(id));
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, putting Java code in a JSP file is considered a poor practice, for sure if it is database interaction code. I suggest to invest some time in learning servlets.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: @ BalusC:Thank You sir for all the help. I will learn servlets properly.